# PrimeFaces dataTable filter by date

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm using PrimeFaces 6.0. 
My problem is when I'm trying to filter my dataTable by a date, it doesn't filter correctly all my lines.

**Code**

```
<p:column headerText="Target Date" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{myBean.targetDate}">
<f:facet name="filter">
    <p:calendar  pattern="MM/yy">
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" oncomplete="PF('dateTable').filter()"/>
    </p:calendar>
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.targetDate}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/yy"/>
</h:outputText>
```

This piece of code works partially. Actually, it doesn't show all the results it should be given.

When I select a date in the calendar, I want to filter by month and year ("MM/yy") without caring about the day.

How can I achieve this? Should I use a converter or my own filter method?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: By creating a custom filter... See the PF docs (and using 'lazyLoading' (including filtering) always provides more control)

Comment: Thank you for your input @Kukeltje I went over the PF docs and found my solution.

Comment: it would be nice if you can share it here with us

Comment: @Hicham It's been a while but I made a custom filter method to solve this problem. All is explained in https://www.primefaces.org/documentation/ in the Filtering section.

Comment: Thanks you @Knriano. I will play with it a little bit